# Show that the application $ Id:( C^1(0,1), \|\cdot\|_{1})\to ( C^1(0,1), \|\cdot\|_{\infty})$ is not continous

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, linear-transformations

I want to prove that the application

$$
Id:( C^1(0,1), \|\cdot\|_{1})\to ( C^1(0,1), \|\cdot\|_{\infty})
$$

is not continous.

If I prove that this application is not bounded I have finished. So I have to find a sequence $\{f_n\}\subset C^1(0,1)$ such that  $\|f_n\|_1 \leq1$ and  $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \geq n$.

I consider 
$$
f_n = \begin{cases} n - n^2x, &x<\frac{1}{n} \\
 0, &x >= \frac{1}{n} \end{cases}
$$
I have that $\|f_n\|_1 = 1/2 < 1$ and $\|f_n\|_{\infty} \geq |f_n(0)| = n$, but with this sequence the condition $\{f_n\}\subset C^1(0,1)$ is not verified.

I have problems in finding a proper sequence in order to prove that $Id$ is not continous.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your definition of the $\|.\|_{1}$-norm?

Comment: Do you know what is mollification?

Comment: @wisher yes I know the mollification

Comment: @user159517 is the $L^1$ norm

Comment: Then use mollification of $f_n$, notice that mollification will only reduce the $L^p$ norm.

Comment: @wisher Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like $f_n(x) = ne^{-nx}$. Then $$\|f_n\|_1 = \int_0^1 ne^{-nx} \, dx = 1 - e^{-n}$$ for all $n$ but $\|f_n\|_\infty = n$.